# SQL Query: Order by in UNION

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union

I am having a bit of a problem with SQL Server 2005 (Express edition) with a UNION query.

I have this table Orders with the following columns: OrdNr, Prio
Now I want to order by orders in 2 ways, the first way is orders that are urgent (so prio 6 or 16) and the second way, the remaining orders sort by Prio.

So this is what my table looks like :

```
ORDNR  PRIO
1       6
2       16
3       2
4       8
```

What I want is this:

```
ORDNR  PRIO
2       16
1       6
4       8
3       2
```

My attempt for a query was this:

```
SELECT OrdNbr, Prio 
FROM Orders
WHERE Prio IN (6,16) 
ORDER BY Prio DESC
UNION
SELECT OrdNbr, Prio 
FROM Orders
WHERE Prio NOT IN (6,16) 
ORDER BY Prio DESC
```

But I get an error from SQL: A syntax error near UNION

Please help :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT OrdNbr, Prio 
  FROM Orders
ORDER BY
  CASE Prio 
    WHEN 16 THEN 0 
    WHEN 6 THEN 1
    ELSE 2 END,  
  Prio DESC
```

Comment: Can you use DISTINCT in this scenario ? When I try to use DISTINCT in your solution I get this error : `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified`

Comment: @darkownage - Why do you need distinct? Do you have duplicate OrdNbr in Orders table?

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson - Yes, we do have duplicate OrdNbr.

Comment: @darkownage I think you have to move `CASE` into field list in that case, ie `SELECT DISTINCT OrdNbr, Prio, CASE Prio ... END AS rank FROM Orders ORDER BY rank ASC, Prio DESC`

Comment: @darkownage - You can do the `distinct` in a sub query. `SELECT OrdNbr, Prio 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT OrdNbr, Prio
        FROM Orders) as O
ORDER BY
  CASE Prio 
    WHEN 16 THEN 0 
    WHEN 6 THEN 1
    ELSE 2 END,  
  Prio DESC`

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: Thanks man, you deserve a statue :D You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this

```
SELECT OrdNbr, Prio 
FROM Orders
WHERE Prio IN (6,16) 
UNION
SELECT OrdNbr, Prio 
FROM Orders
WHERE Prio NOT IN (6,16) 
ORDER BY Prio DESC
```

== edited==
if your Prio field is integer, i think following will work

```
select * from (
SELECT OrdNbr,Prio 
FROM Orders
WHERE Prio IN (6,16) 
UNION
SELECT OrdNbr, Prio 
FROM Orders
WHERE Prio NOT IN (6,16) 
)
ORDER BY Prio DESC
```

Comment: This will not put Prio 6 and 16 before other Prio´s

Comment: This wont give correct order as prio `8` would come before `6`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (if you don't mind adding another output column) is:

```
SELECT OrdNbr, Prio, 1 AS Seq
FROM Orders
WHERE Prio IN (6,16) 
UNION
SELECT OrdNbr, Prio, 2 AS Seq
FROM Orders
WHERE Prio NOT IN (6,16) 
ORDER BY Seq, Prio DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT OrdNbr, Prio
FROM
(
    SELECT OrdNbr, Prio,
     CASE WHEN Prio IN (6,16) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ord
    FROM Orders
) t
ORDER BY ord, Prio;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ordnbr,
       prio,
       CASE prio 
         WHEN 16 THEN 1 
         WHEN 6 THEN 2 
         ELSE 3 
       END AS NewPriority 
FROM   orders 
ORDER  BY newpriority,
          prio DESC

As per the requirement given, 16 and 6 get the first 2 priorities and the remaining Orders should be sorted based on Prio

Only thing is you will be seeing an extra column(NewPriority) which can be masked while displaying in your application.

Plus a tip here is, if an application is being constructed based on this, an Ordernumber (OrdNbr) should be unique.